# Invalid Procedure Call Or Argument (Error 5)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel with this kind of data: 5.25 Kg.
However, I only need work with the number part of the data.
For that purpose, I've created a function to extract only the number which I am interested in.
I've tried to use it in the next procedure but it produces the "invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)" and I don't get what is the root of the problem. Any help?
If you have another idea how to extract easily the number is also welcome :)

```
Sub ExtractNumbers()
Dim m As Long
For m = 2 To 38
Worksheets("Hoja2").Cells(m, "Q").value = (DeleteUnits(Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(m, "L").value))
Next
End Sub

Private Function DeleteUnits(value As String)
DeleteUnits = Left(value, Len(value) - 3)
End Function
```

Comment: Probably `Len(value) - 3` produces an invalid input. You could try using [`Val`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) perhaps.

Comment: What is `value` when the error occurs?

Comment: If there's always a space after the numeric part then `DeleteUnits = Split(value, " ")(0)` should work provided `value` is not zero-length or some type of error value

Comment: @BigBen do you mean using `Val` instead of DeleteUnits function in order to extract number part? It could be a good solution but it didn't work when the data is a decimal, or at least I didn't get it

Comment: @John Coleman the value is the data contained in the cell

Comment: @vbabeginner That says where the data comes from, not what it is when the error is thrown. Basic debugging would determine what that value is.

Comment: ^^^^ `Debug.Print` or use a watch.

Comment: The value is 5.25 Kg

Comment: Unable to reproduce. `? Left("5.25 KG", Len("5.25 KG") - 3)` in the Immediate Window returns `5.25`, as expected. I don't think `value` is what you think it is.

Comment: Indeed that value is. The function works properly if the value is substituted directly or it's written the exact Cell which is taken the value from. I think the problem is the loop to get the row of the cell. When the row is given by "m", then an error is reported, otherwise the function works as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's always a space between the Number and the Units, you don't need vb. This excel formula will work fine:

```
 =VALUE(LEFT(A3,SEARCH(" ",A3)))
```

*Obviously, the formula is extracting the value from cell A3.*

If there may or may/not be a space, this vb will do the trick:

```
Public Function ExtractValue(FromCell As Range)
    
    Dim in1%

    For in1 = 1 To Len(FromCell)
        If Not Mid(FromCell, in1, 1) Like "[.0-9]" Then Exit For
    Next in1
    ExtractValue = Val(Left(FromCell, in1 - 1))

End Function
```

If there may/may not be leading spaces, then you need one more bit of logic:

```
Public Function ExtractValue(FromCell As Range)
    
    Dim in1%, vnVal

''' Belt and braces: Remove any spaces
    vnVal = Replace(FromCell, " ", "")
    
    For in1 = 1 To Len(vnVal)
        If Not Mid(vnVal, in1, 1) Like "[.0-9]" Then Exit For
    Next in1
    ExtractValue = Val(Left(vnVal, in1 - 1))

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Spinner! I had to do a little change, but it works perfectly.
As you can notice, I'm a completely beginner in vba. So, could you tell me how `%` after the variable ìn1`works?, I haven't seen it before

Comment: Glad to help. The most common variables support short-hand declarations of data type:  Variants don't need 'as Variant' and for others you simply append a symbol to variable name (as I have done above). % for integer, # for double, & for long, $ for string.

Comment: I didn't know it. Thank you very much for the explanation :)